# Resource server returning 500 Internal Server error if Authorization server down

Tags: identityserver4

I have a resource API protected using IdentityServer4 OAuth server.

Within my Resource API , I am using

app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(XXX) to protect the API.

If the authentication server is down when the Resource API is starting up , any request to Resource API returns a "500 Internal Server Error" Which is what I expected. How ever the issue is that once the Authentication server is back on, the Resource API continue to return "500 Internal server error"

I expected the Resource API to start working once the Authentication server comes back on-line. That is not the case.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do the logs say? :) It might be that on startup your resource api is trying to fetch the discovery document from your identity server which isnt there. Then again, turn on logging and you will get a better picture

Comment: That is expected behaviour. You need to run Resource API after starting Identity Server. After that you can stop Identity Server.

Comment: Hmm, ok, Somehow does not make sense in a production environment. Cases where IIS recycles processes periodically.